# How integrate register users from main site throuth php? Vbulletin 5

Tags: php, vbulletin

I have site http://example.com. Forum located http://example.com/forum. 
How can I call through api user registration. 
My PHP code:

```
define('VB_ENTRY', 1);
require_once(dirname(__FILE__) . '/../../forum/includes/api/interfaceabstract.php');
require_once(dirname(__FILE__) . '/../../forum/includes/vb5/template/options.php');
require_once(dirname(__FILE__) . '/../../forum/includes/vb5/cookie.php');
require_once(dirname(__FILE__) . '/../../forum/includes/api/interface/collapsed.php');
require_once(dirname(__FILE__) . '/../../forum/includes/api/interface/noncollapsed.php');
require_once(dirname(__FILE__) . '/../../forum/includes/vb5/config.php');
$config = vB5_Config::instance();

$config->loadConfigFile('config.php');

$api = Api_InterfaceAbstract::instance();
print_r($rpassword1);
$data = array(
    'userid'   => 0,
    'password' => $rpassword1,
    'user'     => array('username' => $ruser['user_name'], 'email' => $ruser['user_email']),
    array(),
    array(),
    'userfield' => false,
    array(),
    '',
    array('registration' => true),
);
// save data
$response = $api->callApi('user', 'save', $data, false, true);
```

but it does not work.

Comment: What you are trying to accomplish ? Try to explain better your goal.

Comment: I have a main site (example.com). Which I installed a forum vbulletin 5 (example.com/forum). Now I'm trying to combine the registration. After registration on main site, the forum should also create an account.
The above code I wrote in my controller, where the process of registration.

Comment: Regarding to this post it isn't easy achievable : http://www.vbulletin.com/forum/forum/vbulletin-4/vbulletin-4-questions-problems-and-troubleshooting/4068852-can-site-user-register-for-both-our-site-and-forum-at-the-same-time

Answer (score 1):

I've been working with vBulletin for about a month now and I've figured out that the order of the parameters must be in alphabetical order. For some reason the order that they have their parameters in their documentation is not accurate.  Try rearranging the parameters into alphabetical order and it should work. Thats how I've gotten most of their calls to work so far. #vNightmaretin

Comment: This is a very general answer to a specific problem. Please confirm that your answer is a solution to the question and if so, please add that information to your answer. Otherwise please delete it. Thanks.

Comment: Okay so another month later I've got VBulletin running perfectly and doing everything that I need to integrate their api into my iOS app. which method from their api are you trying to access right now? Can you give me the class and method name?